# Unable to knit using Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

Hello please I get an error message like this 
"Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name" when trying to Knit in Rmarkdown
Code below

```
#Here is how to insert a figure from a file on disk
knitr::include_graphics("C:/Users/OJONG TABI OJONG/Documents/University Documents/Bioinformatics Analysis with R/Assignment 1/Assignment new1Ojtoday/exports/datasets/a19ojooj_rnaseq/qualityReports/RNAseq/Count data/a19ojooj_rnaseq RNAseq Count data PCA.pdf")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and R. Please include a sample of your data and the code which generated this error, so you can help us help you. Have you had a chance to look at the guidance about how to ask a really good question [MRE]?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of R you are running.

Older versions have a bug where you can't include spaces when referencing directories.

Answer (score 0):

to test it out, put the file directly in

```
C:/Users
```

and see if it generates